# Calculating Time Zones in different columns

Tags: google-sheets, time-zone

I'm trying to reflect different time zones across columns.  In Excel, I could just e.g.,

```
=A1+2
```

and it would give me the right time.

```
    A     B     C

    EST   CST   PST

 1  9:30  11:30 13:30

 2  11:00 13:00 14:00
```

etc.

Thoughts on the formula to calculate columns B & C?

Answer (score 3):

When adding `+1` it's adding 24 hours.  So, do this:

```
=A1+1/24
```

to add 1 hour to the time,

```
=A2+2/24
```

for 2 hours, etc.